# How to set intel_idle.max_cstate=1

Tags: intel, idle

How can i set intel idle max cstate to 1 and how can i check when it will done. i have a freeze problem because of bay trail cores.

i tried kernel 4.5   4.1.12  4.4 but freeze problem still continue.
at the moment 4.4 is my kernel version.

Comment: As of now (8/2019) this thread does not actually states that setting the intel_idle.max_cstate=1 is an official  resolution to the bug published in 2011. 
Since in my case it is (had to duplicate) an intermittent problem, before I ADD intel_idle.max_cstate=1 to my GRUB, I like to get some documentation stating that. The original Bugzilla doc are unclear to that effect. 
Can some participant in this forum kindly help me to officially verify this “fix”?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If using GRUB:

With `sudo`, edit `/etc/default/grub` and edit the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line adding `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` to whatever might already be there. After saving the file run `sudo update-grub`, then re-boot. Suggest that you save a copy of your original grub file first.

To check that your cstate is not going deeper than 1 use turbostat (package: linux-tools-common).

Example (where there is already something on the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`):

Before (edited):

```
$ sudo turbostat -S --debug sleep 10
 Avg_MHz   %Busy Bzy_MHz TSC_MHz     SMI  CPU%c1  CPU%c3  CPU%c6  CPU%c7 CoreTmp  PkgTmp Pkg%pc2 Pkg%pc3 Pkg%pc6 PkgWatt CorWatt GFXWatt
       1    0.04    1654    3411       0    0.12    0.03   99.82    0.00      29      29    0.07    0.03   99.51    3.85    0.20    0.23
10.001629 sec
```

Make the change (using my method for configuration control):

```
~/config/etc/default$ cp /etc/default/grub ./
~/config/etc/default$ cp grub grub.original
~/config/etc/default$ nano grub
```

Change this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1"
```

To this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
```

And update:

```
~/config/etc/default$ sudo cp grub /etc/default
~/config/etc/default$ sudo update-grub
~/config/etc/default$ sudo reboot -r now
```

Now check (edited):

```
$ sudo turbostat -S --debug sleep 10
 Avg_MHz   %Busy Bzy_MHz TSC_MHz     SMI  CPU%c1  CPU%c3  CPU%c6  CPU%c7 CoreTmp  PkgTmp Pkg%pc2 Pkg%pc3 Pkg%pc6 PkgWatt CorWatt GFXWatt
       0    0.02    1920    3411       0   99.98    0.00    0.00    0.00      39      39    0.00    0.00    0.00   10.49    6.66    0.23
10.001079 sec
```

Your should also see these messages in `dmesg` and `var/log/kern.log` (edited):

```
~$ dmesg | grep intel_idle
[    1.019709] intel_idle: max_cstate 1 reached

$ grep intel_idle /var/log/kern.log
Mar 23 08:10:32 s15 kernel: [    1.019709] intel_idle: max_cstate 1 reached
```

Comment: I wonder what value, in the output of `turbostat`, is showing that the cstate is not going deeper than 1. What do you mean with `deeper`? What to do differently if it does go deeper?

Comment: @Stephane : By "deeper", I meant higher c states than 1. if you have set the grub command line properly, it shouldn't go to cstate deeper (higher than) 1. You can observe the CPU and Package, cstates greater than 1 show 0.00% time in those states on the turbostat output line.

Comment: My Thinkpad X201i was doing hard restarts every hour. I enabled the `intel_idle.max_cstate=1`in the grub like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"`with a grub update `sudo update-grub` and restarted the machine. No hard restarts occur any more. I(m glad I solved my issue. I wonder what exactly is this property telling the CPU though.

Comment: FYI I've been following this bug report for about a year and it may interest you too: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051. Also here in AU: https://askubuntu.com/questions/803640/system-freezes-completely-with-intel-bay-trail

Answer (score 4):

After having the same freeze-problems with linux and my asrock Q2900 I found on a German IT website the solution/workaround provided by Intel. (https://www.golem.de/news/intel-einfrieren-bei-intels-bay-trail-socs-durch-patch-abgefedert-1609-123546.html)
There is a general problem with Bay-Trail-SoCs from Intel. 
The link to the patch: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=223851

Further information: This patch/script does obtain the power saving mode. The topic-solution above does remove this mode at all.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to update grub anymore if you switch to a most recent kernel.

According to comment# 1013 in [bug report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051) it is now fixed:

> I haven't checked this thread in a long time, but I thought I should
>   post my findings just in case it is of any use to anyone.
>
> A low end computer powered with an Intel N2807 which never worked more
>   than 30 mn without crashing when I didn't set ...max_cstates=1 now
>   works perfectly well with a stock kernel v. 5.3.1 or 4.19.75. I ran it
>   for a couple of days with each version without any issues. The average
>   power consumption was also down by a little over 10%.

It has taken about four years to fix this bug first reported December 8, 2015.

Comment: Can confirm it's no longer required on Ubuntu22.10 on a Dell XPS 9370 at least

Answer (score 2):

Edit /etc/defaults/grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
```

Run

```
update-grub
shutdown -r now
```