# Linux deep freeze after Nvidia-settings upgrade

Tags: kernel, desktop-environments, crash

I turned on my laptop, opened chrome, opened Airdroid on my phone, on chrome on laptop I opened `192.168.1.100:8888` to connect to phone and I clicked on camera so I can see what my phone's camera is seeing on my laptop's screen and right away after clicking, everything froze, I tried EVERYTHING (answers and comments) [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31818/what-to-do-when-a-linux-desktop-freezes) EVERY key sequence.. nothing works, any idea what's going on?

I also had a full `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade` some hours ago but there seemed to be no issue with them.

---

Ok, now I did a hard reboot, and checking `/var/log/syslog`, system didn't even log anything about what happened, there's nothing in there:

```
Feb 28 19:50:06 s-N552VW kernel: [   47.049366] nvidia-modeset: Allocated GPU:0 (GPU-d4ac21de-204f-1b44-bf51-9299897df3d7) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
Feb 28 19:50:06 s-N552VW kernel: [   47.049478] nvidia-modeset: Freed GPU:0 (GPU-d4ac21de-204f-1b44-bf51-9299897df3d7) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
Feb 28 19:50:10 s-N552VW systemd[1]: Starting Stop ureadahead data collection...
Feb 28 19:50:10 s-N552VW systemd[1]: Stopped Read required files in advance.
Feb 28 19:50:10 s-N552VW systemd[1]: Started Stop ureadahead data collection.
Feb 28 21:46:05 s-N552VW rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="1157" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Feb 28 21:46:05 s-N552VW rsyslogd-2222: command 'KLogPermitNonKernelFacility' is currently not permitted - did you already set it via a RainerScript command (v6+ config)? [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2222 ]
Feb 28 21:46:05 s-N552VW rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 108
Feb 28 21:46:05 s-N552VW rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 104
Feb 28 21:46:05 s-N552VW rsyslogd-2039: Could not open output pipe '/dev/xconsole':: No such file or directory [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
Feb 28 21:46:05 s-N552VW rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 10' suspended, next retry is Wed Feb 28 21:46:35 2018 [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Feb 28 21:46:05 s-N552VW systemd-modules-load[406]: Inserted module 'lp'
Feb 28 21:46:05 s-N552VW systemd-modules-load[406]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Feb 28 21:46:05 s-N552VW systemd-modules-load[406]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Feb 28 21:46:05 s-N552VW loadkeys[400]: Loading /etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz
```

It jumps from `19:50:10` to `21:46:05` wth?!

---

Let's have a look at `/var/log/kern.log`:

```
Feb 28 19:49:34 s-N552VW NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1519834774.5220] manager: WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Feb 28 19:49:34 s-N552VW NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1519834774.5220] manager: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Feb 28 19:49:34 s-N552VW kernel: [   15.234933] nvidia-modeset: Allocated GPU:0 (GPU-d4ac21de-204f-1b44-bf51-9299897df3d7) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
Feb 28 19:49:34 s-N552VW kernel: [   15.235040] nvidia-modeset: Freed GPU:0 (GPU-d4ac21de-204f-1b44-bf51-9299897df3d7) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00Feb 28 21:46:05 s-N552VW kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xba, date = 2017-04-09
Feb 28 21:46:05 s-N552VW kernel: [    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0x42/0x50d with crng_init=0
Feb 28 21:46:05 s-N552VW kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.13.0-36-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-033) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9))
```

Seems to be an issue with Nvidia driver, I upgraded package `nvidia-settings` from `390.12-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1` to `390.25-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1`

---

And lastly `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Feb 28 19:49:32 s-N552VW systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user s by (uid=0)
Feb 28 19:49:32 s-N552VW lightdm: pam_ck_connector(lightdm:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0
Feb 28 19:49:34 s-N552VW polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c2 (system bus name :1.53 [/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00Feb 28 21:46:05 s-N552VW systemd-logind[1124]: New seat seat0.
Feb 28 21:46:09 s-N552VW lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I'm asking this from phone thus typos and bad formatting might happen, sorry, It's probably just a matter of time till I give up and do a hard reboot, I hope someone comes up with a solution.. thx

Comment: Hold down Alt+PrintSreeen/SysRq buttons and while those are down, press one key at a time with pause in between: R, E, I, S, U, B.

Comment: Been doing that a couple of times, I also did it again since you instructed, but yeah nothing happens..

Comment: Ok thanks anyway, but this is a rare case, so I'll be sad to just let this go, I could just do a hard reset but then this question will die cause even if someone answers it how would anyone know it would have worked? I wish I could set a bounty on this but I have to wait two days.. and leaving my laptop like this for two days??! How can I live like that!!

Comment: Could this be a kernel panic? shouldn't a kernel panic screen be black? I'm just frozen on my desktop https://prnt.sc/il05e1

Comment: Kernel panics can look like lots of things. What do your logs say?

Comment: I meant to ask that actually, what log files should I look at? Where are they located, I will hard restart in 30 mins if I don't find asolution and I'll look up the logs

Comment: So I thought magic sysrq key was not enabled thus not working, but I tested and it works, and as I guessed correctly I didn't have to hold the `Fn` key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to reproduce this freeze just doing the same procedure.

So as I said in the question, I did an update from Update Manager and I upgraded Nvidia-settings well I had no idea what I was doing, this update was unchecked by default, so I had `Nvidia-387` drivers installed before and with updating I installed `Nvidia settings 390` which is ofc meant to be used with `Nvidia-390` driver not `Nvidia-387` driver which I was using.

```
s@s-N552VW ~/Desktop $ dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  nvidia-387                                  387.34-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2                              amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 387.34
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-387                       387.34-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2                              amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                0.8.2linuxmint1                                         amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                             390.25-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                              amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

Opened up Driver Manager and upgraded to Nvidia 390 and no more freezes!

```
s@s-N552VW ~/Desktop $ dpkg -l | grep nvidia
rc  nvidia-387                                  387.34-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2                              amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 387.34
ii  nvidia-390                                  390.25-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                              amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 390.25
rc  nvidia-opencl-icd-387                       387.34-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2                              amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-390                       390.25-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                              amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                0.8.2linuxmint1                                         amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                             390.25-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                              amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
s@s-N552VW ~/Desktop $
```

And running:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-387
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-opencl-icd-387
```

Seems everything's back to normal:

```
s@s-N552VW ~/Desktop $ dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  nvidia-390                                  390.25-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                              amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 390.25
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-390                       390.25-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                              amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                0.8.2linuxmint1                                         amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                             390.25-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                              amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

**Update Manager suggested update for Nvidia-settings BUT NOT the driver itself.**

Comment: If you think there is a bug in the update manager, please report it using https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: Ohhh now I understand what you're saying, edited out the question part

Comment: I rechecked your edit, and saw it was revised for rant, well I didn't mean to rant but sure looks like it, re-edited to your standard :D