# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Freezing

Tags: freeze, error-handling

I just recently moved from Win10 to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS .3 for a week. Everything was fined except one thing: Ubuntu usually freezes randomly (cant do anything, cant move the mouse or enter any key).

My laptop  is hp 15da0xx, 8GB ram, core i7, 250MB Vram, Graphic card: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does it happen when you use certain software like Chromium or VS Code? Does it happen when the machine is left idle?

Comment: What does `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness` report? This is a common problem when swappiness is set too low.

Comment: If `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness` is set to 60, you might be able to fix the problem by [following these instructions and limiting cstates to 1](https://askubuntu.com/a/749371/167115).

Comment: when it happen i just use google chrome

Comment: i change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT from "quiet splash" to "quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"  and run sudo update-grub, but it's still 60 when i check cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness

Comment: You changed a video setting. How does this affect swap?

Comment: Check your cache. For 8 GB, it should be set to something like 11 GB. See https://linuxhandbook.com/increase-swap-ubuntu/ or https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-20-04